# i am getting an IndexError in this code can you help me?

Tags: python

while loading this code:

```
import bs4 
from urllib.request import urlopen as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
my_url = "https://www.daraz.com.np"
uclient = req(my_url)
page_html = uclient.read()
uclient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
container = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"c3e8SH"})
len(container)
container[0]
```

i got an this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bhatt\my_scrap.py", line 11, in <module>
    container[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What does `print(len(container))` show ? It seems just that your findAll finds nothing

Comment: `container` is empty, therefore 0 is an invalid index. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: how to fix it can you please help me

Comment: print(len(container is showing nothing!!!

Comment: Not possible. Put it before `container[0]` of course, it print something, a number, for sure

Comment: my len is comming zero but there are more products

Comment: Your findAll is wrong so, that's just it

Comment: https://www.daraz.com.np/catalog/?spm=a2a0e.13728030.search.1.16111b82vrWMc2&q=laptop&_keyori=ss&from=search_history&sugg=laptop_0_1    this is the link can you please show me what should be findAll

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "fix it" means? What did you expect to get as a result?

Comment: len of the container

Comment: my answer is coming 0  but there are more product !!! :(

Comment: Please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `container = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"c3e8SH"})` is resulting an empty list.
You can try adding a condition if the container list is not empty then take the first element as

```
container[0] if container else None #or another part that you want to execute in case the container list is empty
```

to overcome this error.

Comment: my len(container is not showing all numbers of product ! can you please help me with that

Comment: You can do `container = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"c3e8SH"})` `print(len(container))` that will print 0 in your case

Comment: how to len all product brother?

Comment: Which products are you looking for? this is a marketplace you can't get all the products from the first page

Comment: i am looking how many products are there !!! we cant see that ?

Comment: You need to find the subpages and then read and parse each one of their content and extract the products.

Comment: You welcome, please vote up and mark the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

it seem that `container = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"c3e8SH"})` is an empty list,
means there is no element having class c3e8SH.